# Is there a way to receive a dataset from a select into a Stored procedure/function parameterin MySQL

Tags: mysql

So, I've been thinkering around with MySQL trying to create a function to create a JSON object from a select query. But I haven't seen any possible way to get just a select query as a parameter for a function or a Stored procedure. Is this even possible?

I've been looking for ways to pass results from a select query but there isn't any way I've found to create a function which gets a select query result as parameter

Comment: Why do you need/want to send the results of a query to a function (or stored procedure) ?  Why not simply send the SQL-statement to it (and use [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html) to get the results inside that function)

Comment: Can you, please, provide a [mre] ?  (some sample data, a query, and expected output ?)

Comment: Why not use the execute statement? because I want to use the results in two different places, I just want to see if there's a way to get the data into a variable and use it, for example into two different procedures. Already tried the way of sending the SQL statement as a string and using the execute function but wanted to know if there might be another way to do it

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such way.

Comment: Or you could store the results in a [temp table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) ?

Comment: In MySQL tables are not a first-class datatype that can be passed as a procedure parameter. Parameters can only be individual values. You could pass the query as a satring, and use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to execute it. Or you could save the results of a query in a table, and the procedure can read from that table.